# why can't I get attribute of '-webkit-mask' by calling jquery .css('-webkit-mask')

Tags: html, jquery, css

I wanna get the '-webkit-mask' attribute of the img element below(in chrome):

```
element.style {
    background: white;
    -webkit-mask: url(Images/menu-icons/fm.png);
    width: 17px;
    height: 19px;
}
```

I can get the correct values of 'background'/'width'/'height' by calling $(img).css('') except '—webkit-mask'， why?

```
$(_img).css('height')
"19px"
$(_img).css('-webkit-mask')
""
```

Comment: `.css('-webkit-mask-image')` works to get the `url(…)` value here, but if you needed to check on other `-webkit-mask-…` properties as well, you might have to do that individually.

Comment: that's exactly  what I want，thank you for your answer